# Python. Проблема со Scapy.arp

Tags: python

Вот код

```
import scapy.all as scapy



def scan(ip):
  arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
  broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
  arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
  answered_list, unanswered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1)
  print(answered_list.summary())

scan("10.0.2.1/24")
```

Выдаёт

Received 0 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 256 packets
None

Должен был выдать список полученных ip и mac-адресов